# odd jQuery text added to ko.observable text

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am experiencing very odd text being appended to ko.observable value that is bind with textarea.

User can type issue in textarea and send to me using ajax/JSON. What I sometimes got is:

"Whatever issue user typed foo bar lorem ipsumjQuery17107608176749199629_1386860692538"

problem is this piece:
"jQuery17107608176749199629_1386860692538" which is sometimes added. I have already found that the 2nd part "_1386860692538" is time stamp and may vary. first part "17107608176749199629" remains constant - but I have no idea what does it mean.

has anybody any idea what causes this issue?

```
var issue = {};
issue.description = viewModelIssue.description();
issue.type = $("#selectType option:selected").val();

var jsonData = ko.toJSON(issue);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: A_URL_HERE,
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) { },
    complete: function () { }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean - sometimes? Can you post some code?

Comment: You're using `jsonp`.

Comment: just added code example

Comment: "What I sometimes got is" what you mean exactly by `sometimes` ?

Comment: about 100 issues were send correctly, and 2 of them were send with this weird 'jQueryNUMBER_TIMESTAMP' thing. I can't reproduce it as it happend on live server (2 servers with load balancer).

as someone has mentioned - this seems to be a JSONP callback - but I have no idea why it is added to my 'description' ko.observable variable. really odd stuff.

Comment: try to use static JSON string and check if you still have this issue or not? maybe it's something with `ko.toJSON`

Comment: Unrelated, but you can use `issue.type = $("#selectType").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what causes error... however don't know yet how to fix it.

I am using knockout and jQuery ajax call, and if in any textbox or textarea that goes through AJAX to server I type '??' (double question marks) it got replaced by this odd jqueryNUMBER_NUMBER text.

any idea why???????

### edit:

got solution - just add "jsonp: false":

```
$.ajax({
    (...)
    jsonp: false,
    success: function (results) {},
    (...)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataType` being sent is defined as `jsonp` and not `json`, which causes jQuery to return the results wrapped in a callback function (the "weird name" you're seeing).
If you intent to use cross-domain AJAX calls, you can define the name for the callback function using the parameter `jsonp`.

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
> Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
> server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
> MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
> JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
> script, and anything else will be returned as a string).
>
> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra
> "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables
> caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the
> URL unless the cache option is set to true.
>
> ...
>
> jsonp Type: String Override the callback function name in a jsonp
> request. This value will be used instead of 'callback' in the
> 'callback=?' part of the query string in the url. So
> {jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'} would result in 'onJSONPLoad=?' passed to the
> server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the jsonp option to false prevents
> jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to
> use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly
> set the jsonpCallback setting. For example, { jsonp: false,
> jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: thanks MelanciaUK,

I have just added code example to my post above. can you please check if I got any error there? I don't see using JSONP anywhere.

Comment: Check if the URL has the parameter `callback` as part of its query string.

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue, as it happens rarely on live server. My URL has no word 'callback'. dataType is explicitlt set to 'json'. 

what is more - I have load balancer, so very rarely user can be redirected to 2nd server if one failed. is it possible that this causes to use JSONP (instead of JSON) in background?

Comment: As the result is coming wrapped in a jQuery function, it's guaranteed that it returned as `jsonp`. The problem will be for you to reproduce the error and spot where things are getting out of your control.